# Re-structuring a sentence

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

I want to say without being nasty that this person is "very self-assured at times and needs to tone it down a little and she comes across as being cocky about her knowledge. At times over confident".

How could I re-structure this sentence?

Thanks
Azil

Comment: Re-structuring means saying exactly the same thing, with the same nuances, using a different structure. Are you asking for a hedged (less confrontational) rewrite?

Comment: This entirely depends on the context. I would share some more details. Are you writing to a member of staff? To a friend you work with? To a student buddy? Are there specific examples of this behaviour that you can recollect? If so can you share them? If you've already tried to rewrite the sentence yourself, perhaps you could share some of your other examples. If you've looked elsewhere to figure out how you rewrite it, it would be a good idea to add those references to your question. This further detail will (a) encourage more people to answer your question, (b) ensure the answer is relevent.

Comment: Also I'm assuming (which isn't always a great idea) that you mean re-write, as per Edwin's original comment and not re-structure (i.e. the answer can use entirely new words, phrases, clauses and meanings.) it would be a good idea to clarify if this is the case also in your question.

Comment: Yes that is correct re-write....have a student who is quite knowledgeable & knows it but her attitude is a little over the top when she explains herself and will put other students down because they may not be as knowledgeable as herself etc.

Answer (score -2):

Lacking justification and/or examples, what you're saying actually is nasty; substituting with synonyms and restructuring won't change that.

You are insinuating the person in question is a bad judge of their own ability.  To believe such a thing requires either evidence or malice.

Comment: Hi, Im writing a reference for a new graduate position in nursing, thanks Azil